# How do time zones work with CiviCRM?

Tags: civievent, timezone

I am using EventICS and some event registrants are reporting that the calendar item they get is for the wrong time, but when they forward to us, its correct, so we think its an issue with time zones. In the docs, I can't seem to find any reference to time zones, so I am posting here to get more clarity. How do time zones work with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 4):

This might be https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2887. Are they Outlook users?

Comment: It's very strange as it doesn't affect all Outlook users, just some

Comment: Justin at Agileware is shortly to start work on a fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

I see we made an extension described as

**Event ICal Timezone**

> Sets time on the ical file as per the timezone set on the user's device

I can't comment on how well it might meet your need but happy to provide it if you want to give it a try if it sounds useful

Comment: I am willing to give it a try.

Comment: pls email me peter.davis at fuzion.co.nz